# OleDBException 0x80040e10 No value Given

Tags: vb.net, oledb

The first part of this works correctly, when the Textbox value is null. It throws an exception however, when i try to filter search using the second part of the if statement.

The reason the table var is set that way is because the user has the option to load different tables.

The textbox string is the search parameter.

```
Public Class form1

    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= .\Service.accdb ;")
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter

 Private Sub getdata()
        Me.Refresh()

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim table As String = ComboBox1.Text.ToString
        Dim txt As String = TextBox1.Text.ToString

        If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then

            con.Open()
            da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from [" & table & "] ;", con)
            con.Close()
        Else

            con.Open()
            da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from [" & table & "] where (External like '%" & txt & "%' or Internal like '%" & txt & "%' or Code like '%" & txt & "%');", con)
            con.Close()
        End If

        Try
            da.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT

It seems that this bit of code is stopping it from searching correctly, however without it i cannot save to the DB..

```
    Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    builder.QuotePrefix = "["
    builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```

So i am assuming i am missing a paramter from this section?

Comment: Make sure your table has those three columns: External, Internal and Code.  Surround them in brackets, just in case.

Comment: It does, and in the case it doesn't that is what the OR statments are for. Out of 9 tables this works in 3 which have all either do or don't carry one of these columns.

Comment: The OR won't short circuit the query.  ALL your tables need ALL those fields.

Comment: Even with the tables holding each of these column names, it is still giving the error of No Value given for one or more Required Parameters.